# Finding Outliers and replacing with Mean value in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am currently working on a assignment where i need to **find the Outliers & replace them with Average/Mean of previous 2 and next 2 values in the column**.
I have this below 2 columns as a Data Frame.
Sample data show below.
[image]

Kindly let me know how to achieve this using Data Frames. Any suggestions would be of Good help. Thank you.

Comment: Is it performed with some grouping? How do you determine order? What language do you use?

Comment: Yes right its performed with Grouping of CustomerID. I am using Scala

Comment: What about the ordering? And do you want to use dataset mean and standard deviation or per customer?

Comment: i have not used orderby and want to use it per customer.

Comment: It doesn't answer my question. If there is no explicit ordering how do you define preceding / subsequent values? Is there any timestamp field?

Comment: Hi sorry, should have mentioned. i have a time-stamp field.

Comment: One more question. How do you define `AvgActualWin` / `StdDev`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution to my above question.
Using the HiveContext Window function we can identify the rows before & after the outlier detection & replace them. Below is the sample code.
    val w = Window.partitionBy("CustomerID").orderBy("EventDate")
    val before = w.rowsBetween(-2,-1)
    val after = w.rowsBetween(1,2)